# How do I properly json_encode ["number" => 12, "color" => "1e3673"] in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm writing an API. The API always returns JSON. Internally, the response data is an array that is converted to JSON like so:

```
<?php
function toJson($responseData) {
  return json_encode($responseData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

This makes sure that numbers are represented as integers (and not as strings) in the JSON. 99.9% of the time, this works great. However, it dies in the following instance:

```
<?php
toJson(array('color' => '1e3673'));
```

The reason it dies is that PHP thinks "1e3673" is a number in scientific notation and converts it into an integer. But the integer is too large, and ends up being represented as +INF, which cannot be represented in JSON. So json_encode fails completely.

**How can I handle this situation correctly?** It seems my options are

1. Somehow tell PHP that "1e3673" is not a number.
2. Stop using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK. This will make the API really annoying to use with many languages (e.g. Javascript), and seems like a terrible way to handle this narrow corner case.
3. Write my own JSON encoder that avoids this issue.

I would prefer #1, but am open to #3 if that's necessary. Or maybe there's another way?

Comment: 4. Denote the color as `#1e3673` or `0x1e3673`.

Comment: `2`! You must be able to response with `"00012"` or `"11.09"` string. Just check your methods to response correct types.

Comment: I can't reproduce "dying" here. PHP 5.6 and 7.0 both work as expected for me.

Comment: Neither do I. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a9ffcf6119cf15559b26849eb0c89e6b221f374 returns `{"color": "1e3673"}`.

Comment: Apparently this was fixed sometime between 5..6.2 and 5.6.17. So I guess the real solution is "update my PHP". Thanks for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug, which is fixed in versions 5.5.23+, 5.6.7+, 7.0+.

https://3v4l.org/aHt34